# Chemical catalogue index

Tags: publications, citations

I am writing a report for a paper using APA format. which used specific antibodies and other chemicals in the process of obtaining tissue samples and am confused as to where I should include the catalogue number, company, and company location of the chemical.

Should I include this in my references or as a separate appendix?

Is there a rule of standard for including something like this?

Note: I am using LaTeX's APA6 package for the paper.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the journal and their layouts. Most will have a "Materials and methods" parts, this is where you write down which instruments and chemicals were used. At least in chemistry there are no common rules about how in detail this should be. You will read something like this very commonly:

> All commercially available analytical grade chemical reagents were purchased from Aldrich (St. Louis, MO) and used without further purification.

But you can include more information here, like CAS number, catalogue number and so on.

Sometimes this section isn't present in the paper itself and you might include it in the supplementary information.

In the end it's important to include all the relevant data in a useful way and it doesn't really matter how you do it.